# Run npm install + gulp, when deploying clojure app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, clojure, npm, gulp

Is there a way for me to run npm install and then gulp when deploying a Clojure app to heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use [Heroku's Multi-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi) with the Node.js and Clojure buildpacks. This is documented for [Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks) and [Scala](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-node-js-to-perform-javascript-optimization-for-play-and-scala-applications).

Comment: Thanks, I just ended up building my own buildpack

Comment: Cool. While it's great that folks can create their own buildpacks, there is an advantage to using the Heroku supported buildpacks. They are updates regularly with security fixes for the JDK and other components. Heroku can also provide a better level of support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm's scripts in your package.json. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process